# iOS blocking HTTPS request

Tags: ipad, ssl, https

I have a valid SSL certificate, provider DigiCert. No problems.

When I visit my webapp on the iPad I recently found out that some parts was not working properly. Going further debugging, I connected the iPad to the Mac so i could use the web dev tool and found then the following:

[image]

I really don't get this? Why does it block these, even analytics and fonts from Google?

I receive no such errors on any other browsers or devices than this new iPad 2 mini.

Testing with an older iPad 2nd gen, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the date and time configuration of the ipad right?

Comment: Wow... that was really it. our kid must have messed with the settings. thank you